# Populating an angular2-datatable from a webapi

Tags: angular

I'm currently trying to use angular2-datatable (from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable) in my project and when I do a simple version with a static .json file, it works. However, when I try to implement this against my WebAPI, it doesn't actually show the data in the component.

In my component, I have the following:

```js
export class CurrentusersComponent implements OnInit {

  public data;
  public filterQuery = "";
  public rowsOnPage = 10;
  public sortBy = "username";
  public sortOrder = "asc";

  currentusers: Currentuser[];


  constructor(private _http: Http, private _currentusersservice: CurrentusersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //this loadCurrentUsersStatic works!
    this.loadCurrentUsersStatic();

    //this loadCurrentUsersNonObservable Does not :(
    this.loadCurrentUsersNonObservable();
  }

  loadCurrentUsersStatic() {
    this._http.get("app/auth/sampledata/currentusers.json")
      .subscribe((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.data = data.json();
          console.log('getting data from a static file');
        }, 1000);
      }, );
  }

  loadCurrentUsersNonObservable() {
    this._currentusersservice.getCurrentUsers().subscribe(
      data => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.data = data;
          console.log(data);
        }, 1000);
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is what the components template looks like:

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">User information</div>

  <table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 20%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="username">User Name</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 10%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="logintime">Login Time</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="sessionkey">Session Key</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 25%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="currentpage">Current Page</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 10%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="browser">Browser</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 5%">
          <mfDefaultSorter by="status">Status</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th style="width: 5%">Action
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
        <td>{{item.username}}</td>
        <td>{{item.logintime}}</td>
        <td>{{item.sessionkey}}</td>
        <td>{{item.currentpage}}</td>
        <td>{{item.browser}}</td>
        <td>{{item.status}}</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

My currentusersservice looks like the following:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CurrentusersService {

  public data;
  constructor(private _http: Http, private _cookieService: CookieService) {}

  getCurrentUsers() {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:8888/api/currentusers')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map(body => body.Data);
  }
```

When I look at the end result, I get the following:

[image]

Notice that in the console, I see the many records as objects and even the table is populating a number of rows. So I think I'm just missing something in terms of getting the data onto the screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to get rid of `.map(body => body.Data);` in your service

Comment: Hi Yevgen, no this wasn't correct. My json actually has multiple components, with Data being a tree that contains the array of info that I need. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like ngFor / accessing the json is case sensitive :p

The data became accessible when I changed my template to loop through with these calls:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
  <td>{{item.USERNAME}}</td>
  <td>{{item.LOGINTIME}}</td>
  <td>{{item.SESSIONKEY}}</td>
  <td>{{item.CURRENTPAGE}}</td>
  <td>{{item.BROWSER}}</td>
  <td>{{item.STATUS}}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

I should have realized this when I saw that the details of the object were being labeled with all caps...